# EVP_MD_CTX_destroy segfaults when linking to a dynamic lib using openssl 1.1

Tags: c++, openssl, shared-libraries

Our application has always been using an in house developed shared lib which dynamically links to openssl 1.0 (the actual EVP_xxx symbols in our lib are undefined). So far so good.

This week I've been integrating a 3rd party shared library which has defined openssl 1.1 symbols in it, causing our openssl 1.0 code path to crash.

How is this possible? The 1.0 code path uses EVP_MD_CTX_create and EVP_MD_CTX_destroy, whereas the 3rd party lib introduces EVP_MD_CTX_new and EVP_MD_CTX_free. So that shouldn't be it.

In between the allocation and the destruction, there are a couple of SSL operations going on, for example EVP_DigestSignInit.
I notice that this symbols exists both in 1.0 and 1.1. Is it possible that when linking the 3rd party shared lib, which has this symbol defined, the 1.1 version is being linked to, causing mayhem on an object allocated by EVP_MD_CTX_create ?

If yes, how to avoid having these 1.1 symbols messing up our 1.0 code path?

Potentially relevant details: C++14, GCC, Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this possible?

On Linux (and other UNIX) loading two different versions of `openssl` (or any other shared library) is unsafe and will almost always lead to bugs or crashes.

This is because (by design) UNIX shared libraries are not isolated from each other (unlike Windows DLLs). The first library to define any given symbol "wins", and all uses of that symbol will use the first definition, even when subsequent library also defines that symbol.

The best approach is to use a single version of `openssl`.

You *might* be able to use two incompatible libraries in a single process using `dlmopen` (which is Linux/GLIBC-specific), but you should be prepared to endure a lot of pain if you choose that route.

Comment: Can't I use your implib tool to reduce the visible symbols from the 3rdparty lib? I have no need to see their openssl 1.1 symbols. And maybe that is enough to fix the issue.

Comment: @Bob "Can't I use your implib tool ..." -- no. I don't think you've understood the answer. Once two conflicting libraries are loaded into the same linker namespace, all bets are off.

Comment: I could not link against the 3rd party lib, and use a wrapper generated by your tool? Which would give me more control over the symbols? It is entirely possible that I missed the point of your tool though, haven't had an in depth look yet.

Comment: @Bob 1. It's not _my_ tool. 2. Like I said, it wouldn't help -- once the second version of `openssl` is loaded (the tool only _delays_ such loading), it will clash with the first version and crash.

Comment: Ok thanks, I know enough for now. We'll probably upgrade to 1.1 or ask the supplier to downgrade to 1.0